# How to convert <sqlite3.Row object at 0x0000019393a725f0> into plaintext?

Tags: python, html, database, sqlite, flask

I asked a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76354183/database-returns-sqlite3-row-object-at-0x0000019494a725f0-instead-of-data?noredirect=1#comment134643168_76354183) about an sqlite3 error. The solution to which was "var in [r[0] for r in list]". However this doesn't work for other purposes such as checking password hashes. Since a password hash won't always be the same, I need to use to check_password_hash() function from werkzeug instead. To do this I need to convert <sqlite3.Row object at 0x0000019393a725f0> into plaintext since it won't let me split it. Anyone know how to?

This is my code if you're curious (doesn't work - Line 14):

```
@app.route('/login', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    db = get_db()
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/home')
    else:
        if request.method == "POST":
            id = request.form["id"]
            email = request.form["email"]
            db_id = db.execute('SELECT UserID FROM Users WHERE Email = \"%s\"' % email).fetchall()
            if int(id) in [r[0] for r in db_id]:
                password = request.form["password"]
                db_password = db.execute('SELECT Password FROM Users WHERE Email = \"%s\"' % email).fetchone()
                check = check_password_hash(db_password, password)
                if check == 'True':
                    user = User(id, email)
                    login_user(user)
                    return render_template('Home.html', title='Home Page')
                else:
                    return render_template('Exist.html', title='Login Page')
            else:
                return render_template('Exist.html', title='Login Page')
```

I tried using var in [r[0] for r in list] but since hashes are always different, this doesn't work. It also  wouldn't let me use check_password_hash(password, db_password) since "AttributeError: 'sqlite3.Row' object has no attribute 'split'." I tried sending the variable to the html page but it comes up as sqlite.Row object instead of the actual data.

Comment: you just want to retrieve the value from the row, so `db_password["Password"]`. note, `db_password` is a misleading name, you actually have a `sqlite.Row` object, which represents the data in the row.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the single item from the db, `fetchone()` returns a Tuple

```
password = request. Form["password"]
db_password = db.execute('SELECT Password FROM Users WHERE Email = \"%s\"' % email).fetchone()
```

if you were to `print(db_password)` after that line you'd see something like:

```
("7ea3ef8bf512d82fec11e32a11175af0a803d834",)
```

With the nonsense being the password hash. You need to change the next line to use the first element of the tuple:

```
check = check_password_hash(db_password[0], password)
```